# Variable assignment not working (Observable.subscribe or Observable.map)

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm not really understanding the chain here, despite other StackOverflow posts I've seen.

I have a service that I'm polling repeatedly:

```
getById(id: number): Observable<QueueItem> {
    let URL = this._queueUrl + "/" + id;
    return this._http.get(URL)
        .map((response: Response) => <QueueItem>response.json());
}
```

My caller of the service is polling it repeatedly like so:

```
getQueueItemStatus() {
    IntervalObservable.create(5000)
        .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.queueService.getById(this.id)
                .subscribe(queueItem => {
                    this.queueItem = queueItem;
                    if (queueItem) {
                        if (queueItem.result !== null) {
                            this.isExport = true;
                        }

                        if (queueItem.statusId > 0) {
                            this.inqueue = true;
                            this.alive = false;
                        } else {
                            this.inqueue = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
}
```

After all this, I'm going to show a dialog and do some stuff.  I don't think exactly what I do is relevant, because my problem is this line:

```
this.queueItem = queueItem;
```

That line doesn't seem to work, regardless of the value of `queueItem`.  `null`, `undefined`, or a valid value, that assignment never seems to happen.  And I need it to.

I understand that the value may not have come in yet, but how can I verify when it does?  I'm a little lost here, in that I feel like I'm several `subscribe()` calls deep and getting a little confused.

Would I be better off if the service method didn't return an `Observable`, but just the `QueueItem` directly?  Is that even possible with Angular's HTTP?

Also, I tried replacing `subscribe()` on the service handler (`this.queueService.getById(this.id).subscribe(...)`) with `map()` and none of that code ran at all, so that was a bust.

Comment: Can you change .map((response: Response) => <QueueItem>response.json()); to .map(response => response.json()); and try

Comment: `queueItem` is defined at the point of that assignment because that is what the subscription does. However, I'm not clear what `this.queueItem` refers to. In the languages I'm familiar with, `this` refers to the immediately enclosing class. You think it refers to the outermost class. Is that correct?

Comment: @Sreemat That didn't do anything, unfortunately.  I know the service works, because eventually I get a valid item that comes back.  But when it comes back and tries to assign it to the variable, the variable remains undefined.

Comment: @BobDalgleish That's a good point, but it somehow seems to work.  I'm guessing it's the semantics of how the Javascript is transpiled or the fact that it's in a lambda or something, but the code definitely recognizes that `this` is in the parent component to the code.

Comment: Consider simplifying the code temporarily to narrow down the issue. For example, try taking off the outer `IntervalObservable` and ensure that the basic service function works first. Then add the `IntervalObservable` part back. That could help you identify where the problem is.